# How to display category and subcategory?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

How to display category and subcategory ?
I have one table in DB. Row in this table looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

I want display category and subcategory like on this site: http://www.dealsdirect.com.au/c/baby-1/ (menu on the left)

My try:

```
<?php 
include 'Category_model.php'; 
include 'Advert_model.php'; 
$nr = $_GET['id']; 

function show_category($nr){ 


    try 
        { 
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=advert', 'root', ''); 
            $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

            $stmt = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM category where `parent_id` = $nr"); 


            echo "<ul>";  

            foreach ($stmt as $row){ 
                echo "<li><a href=category_view.php?id={$row['id']}> {$row['name']}</a>".show_category($row['id'])."</li>"; 

                } 
                echo "</ul>"; 
                //$id = $_GET['id']; 
                } 






       catch(PDOException $e) 
                { 
           echo 'Error!: ' . $e->getMessage(); 

           } 

   } 

   show_category($nr);
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do. Please "algorithm"/step how to do

Answer (score 1):

The below code should get you started. It's a "recursive function" - a function that calls itself. As @Fake51 has just mentioned, it's not very efficient, but it should work.

You'll need some CSS to structure the list you've produced.

```
function showItems($parent = 0) {
    $q = "SELECT id, name FROM category WHERE parent_id = $parent";
    $q = mysql_query($q);
    if(mysql_num_rows($q)) {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($r = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href=\"page.php?id=".$r[0]."\">".htmlentities($r[1])."</a>";
            showItems($r[0]);
            echo "</li>"\n;
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}
showItems();
```

Edit: Since there's still been no accepted answer, here's my code modified to do it all with a single SQL query which should be much more efficient, albeit a little more confusing potentially. See how it goes for you.

```
//Recursive function to show menu items from a passed in array
function showItems(&$menu, $parent = 0) {
    if(is_array($menu[$parent]) && sizeof($menu[$parent])) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($menu[$parent] as $num=>$name) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href=\"page.php?id=".$num."\">".htmlentities($name)."</a>";
            showItems($menu, $num);
            echo "</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
}

//Create a multi-dimensional array of ALL menu items, separated by parent
$menu = array();
$q = "SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM category ORDER BY order";
$q = mysql_query($q);
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
    $menu[$r[2]][$r[0]] = $r[1];
}

//Call the function
showItems($menu);
```

Comment: You'll first need to connect with `mysql_connect()` and select a database with `mysql_select_db()`. You should be able to convert this to work with the PDO if you want.

Comment: This is terrible. I would much rather do a single select, get array of all categories and then work with that one array. Also if you can add another field to your categories table 'has_children' and store value like yes/no or boolean, that would allow you to use a more efficient algorithm

Comment: Results should be fetched in single query and then processed by recursive function that builds menu.

Comment: Agree that repeating the query is sub-optimal. A single query building a set of arrays would be a far better method. Some form of caching would also be a smart idea as it's probably unlikely to change often. I went with this as it's simple to get started from, probably should've suggested this change though.

Answer (score 0):

With a structure like that, you'll need to first construct a query for the chosen item, then afterwards construct a query for the chosen items parent. Essentially, you'll need a query for each level of menus you have, that should be visible.

This is the reason why a parent_id scheme of tree relationship is not very efficient. Much better to go with nested set (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) or materialized path (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_path). If you expect to do some updating of the items, materialized path will probably be easier to deal with in the long run - I personally much prefer it, having tried both.

Comment: No true at all. You can select all rows, ideally index them by id, then traverse and build your result.

Comment: That is a waste of resources as you'll not need all results - there can be loads of sub-category items hidden that you need no details of. Apart from that, traversing and building the result in php will be slower than doing it in the database, if you have a proper structure.

Answer (score -1):

Since you only need category and all its subcategories displayed you don't need recursion for menu construction, and you certainly don't want recursion in your DB calls. So most basic solution (all code in one file) would be something like this:

```
<?php 
include 'Category_model.php'; 
include 'Advert_model.php'; 

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=advert', 'root', ''); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$nr = $_GET['id'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM category where `parent_id` = :id or `id` = :id';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $nr));
$menuCategories = $sth->fetchAll();

// If sub category id is passed fetch whole menu
if ((1 == count($menuCategories)) && ($nr == $menuCategories[0]['id'])) {
    $nr = $menuCategories[0]['parent_id'];
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $nr));
    $menuCategories = $sth->fetchAll();
}

$parentCategoryFormat = '<h5><a href="category_view.php?id=%s">%s</a></h5>';
$subCategoryFormat = '<li><a href="category_view.php?id=%s">%s</a></li>';
$parentCategoryHTML = '';
$subMenuHTML = '';
foreach ($menuCategories as $row) {
    if ($row['id'] == $nr) {
        $parentCategoryHTML = sprintf($parentCategoryFormat, $row['id'], htmlentities($row['name'])); // Render parent category
    } else {
        $subMenuHTML .= sprintf($subCategoryFormat, $row['id'], htmlentities($row['name'])); // Render subcategory
    }
 }

 echo $parentCategoryHTML;
 if (!empty($subMenuHTML)) {
      echo "<ul>{$subMenuHTML}</ul>";
 }
```

Comment: And when you click on a sub-category, $nr will be the id of the subcategory hence only fetching one row, not the entire visible tree.

Not to mention the failed quoting in the sql as well as the sql expoit vector in your code.

Comment: @Fake51 Well noticed, thanks. I updated code example. I should probably point out that even this updated code is not production quality, I just wanted to show with this code that in this specific case there is no need for recursion, especially recursion with DB queries, if more complex (deeper) menu structure is needed, better solution is to change 'category' DB table structure like you proposed in your answer.